# Convertir tipos de datos en dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, type

Quiero convertir los tipos de datos del dataframe df1, que son todos de tipo string al que corresponde a cada uno (texto, numericos y fechas)

```
vcl = {'refer': ['757', '172',  '128',  '231',  '164',  '606',  '318',  '236',  '401',  '458',  '114',  '183',  '328',  '973',  '178'],
       'kms':   ['71',  '37',   '68',   '69',   '61',   '24',   '27',   '22',   '15',   '15',   '29',   '12',   '21',   '8',    '10'],
       'model': ['MAZDA',   'BMW',  'MAZDA',    'KIA',  'HYUNDAI',  'KIA',  'SKODA',    'SKODA',    'SKODA',    'MAZDA',    'BMW',  'HYUNDAI',  'HYUNDAI',  'SKODA',    'HYUNDAI'],
       'sistem': ['ACF',    'ACF',  'FRF',  'FRF',  'FRF',  'MSI',  'MSI',  'ACF',  'RWD',  'RWD',  'ACF',  'RWD',  'MSI',  'MSI',  'SWF'],
       'gradient': ['41757.0',  '38057.0',  '21757.0',  '34757.0',  '80157.0',  '35041.0',  '23175.0',  '35875.0',  '31997.0',  '32141.0',  '32941.0',  '12497.0',  '48041.0',  '20141.0',  '77458.0'],
       'inject': ['1.65',   '5.21', '3.23', '2.41', '4.65', '3.70', '3.77', '2.72', '2.26', '1.50', '0.78', '1.34', '1.70', '1.46', '1.05'],
       'date': ['04/12/2019','07/12/2019','01/11/2019','23/11/2019','12/11/2019','19/11/2019','02/11/2019', '23/10/2019',   '19/10/2019',   '10/10/2019',   '14/10/2019',   '28/09/2019',   '21/09/2019',   '24/09/2019',   '07/09/2019'],
       'num_week':['2018-49',   '2018-49',  '2018-44',  '2018-47',  '2018-46',  '2018-47',  '2018-44',  '2018-43',  '2018-42',  '2018-41',  '2018-42',  '2018-39',  '2018-38',  '2018-39',  '2018-36']
       }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(vcl, columns = ['refer', 'kms','model','sistem', 'gradient','inject','date','num_week']) 
print(type(df1) )
```

He probado con df1.infer_objects(), pero no los convierte todos. Deberían quedar asi:

```
refer       int64
kms         int64
model       object
sistem      object
gradient    float64
inject      float64
date        datetime
num_week    datetime
```

Agradecería cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la función `.astype()` para modificar el tipo de dato de la columna, esta función recibirá un diccionario con el nombre de la columna como clave y el tipo que le deseas asignar.
La asignación soporta tipos de datos de `numpy`.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(vcl, 
                   columns = ['refer', 'kms','model','sistem', 'gradient','inject','date','num_week']).astype({
                    'refer':int, 'kms':int, 'model':str, 'sistem':str, 'gradient':float, 'inject':float,
                    'date':str, 'num_week':str})
df1.dtypes
```

> Es importante mencionar que si una columna tiene tipos de datos mixtos, esta quedará como object. Deberás ejecutar una función lambda para la columna, limpiar los datos y luego asignarle el tipo de dato correspondiente.

Entonces tu código quedaría algo así:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
vcl = {'refer': ['757', '172',  '128',  '231',  '164',  '606',  '318',  '236',  '401',  '458',  '114',  '183',  '328',  '973',  '178'],
       'kms':   ['71',  '37',   '68',   '69',   '61',   '24',   '27',   '22',   '15',   '15',   '29',   '12',   '21',   '8',    '10'],
       'model': ['MAZDA',   'BMW',  'MAZDA',    'KIA',  'HYUNDAI',  'KIA',  'SKODA',    'SKODA',    'SKODA',    'MAZDA',    'BMW',  'HYUNDAI',  'HYUNDAI',  'SKODA',    'HYUNDAI'],
       'sistem': ['ACF',    'ACF',  'FRF',  'FRF',  'FRF',  'MSI',  'MSI',  'ACF',  'RWD',  'RWD',  'ACF',  'RWD',  'MSI',  'MSI',  'SWF'],
       'gradient': ['41757.0',  '38057.0',  '21757.0',  '34757.0',  '80157.0',  '35041.0',  '23175.0',  '35875.0',  '31997.0',  '32141.0',  '32941.0',  '12497.0',  '48041.0',  '20141.0',  '77458.0'],
       'inject': ['1.65',   '5.21', '3.23', '2.41', '4.65', '3.70', '3.77', '2.72', '2.26', '1.50', '0.78', '1.34', '1.70', '1.46', '1.05'],
       'date': ['04/12/2019','07/12/2019','01/11/2019','23/11/2019','12/11/2019','19/11/2019','02/11/2019', '23/10/2019',   '19/10/2019',   '10/10/2019',   '14/10/2019',   '28/09/2019',   '21/09/2019',   '24/09/2019',   '07/09/2019'],
       'num_week':['2018-49',   '2018-49',  '2018-44',  '2018-47',  '2018-46',  '2018-47',  '2018-44',  '2018-43',  '2018-42',  '2018-41',  '2018-42',  '2018-39',  '2018-38',  '2018-39',  '2018-36']
       }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(vcl, 
                   columns = ['refer', 'kms','model','sistem', 'gradient','inject','date','num_week']).astype({
                    'refer': np.int64, 'kms':np.int64, 'model':object, 'sistem':object, 'gradient':np.float64, 'inject':np.float64,
                    'date':np.datetime64, 'num_week':object})
df1.dtypes
```

**Nota:** La ultima columna no tiene un formato de fecha adecuado, por lo cual a esa columna deberás aplicar una función lambda para luego cambiarle el tipo. Dado que el día a asignarle a la fecha es un poco a criterio, te dejo resolverlo a ti, luego solo debes aplicar el mismo casteo que la columna anterior.

**SALIDA**

```
refer                int64
kms                  int64
model               object
sistem              object
gradient           float64
inject             float64
date        datetime64[ns]
num_week            object
dtype: object
```